# How to send file between two socket-io client without involving any database?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I would like to send an image between two clients. I am using nodejs and socketio.

Basically i want to achieve this functionality -

> "There are two clients, connected to a nodejs sever. Both clients
>   should be able exchange images and server should not store it
>   anywhere. More specifically it should be in the physical memory of
>   server only"

Comment: Read this please https://stackoverflow.com/a/26331826/5559590

Comment: Basically i want to achieve this functionality - "There are two clients, connected to a nodejs sever. Both clients should be able exchange images and server should not store it anywhere. More specifically it should be in the physical memory of server only".