# Sending file data via Socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, base64, chat

I'm making a chat applicatin using socket.io. I want user to be able to send image and this image will be uploaded to cloudinary then saved to mongodb. First i get base64 string of image but this base64 text could not send via socket.io. So i converted base64 to buffer then sent this via socket.io but now i dont know what to do. Do you have any tips? Why base64 text could not sent via socket.io?

MY CODE WHEN I TRIED TO SEND AS BASE 64

```
socket.emit("send message", here will be the result of file reader)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59478402/how-do-i-send-image-to-server-via-socket-io

Comment: @SardorekAminjonov when i try to send base64 text with socket.io it can't be send. Maybe it's because text is too big. What should I do?

Comment: Images are not too big, usually. So, it should actually work. Can you paste the code? Or it is hard to know what might be going?