# can i use canvas.toDataURL("image/webp", 0.5) in a web worker for better performance?

Tags: javascript, performance

I want to share the image inside a `canvas` to a web socket, for showing in a different html but,
the fps conter shows arrount 20 to 8 fps, and I think the problem is, convert the canvas into a base64 url.
I want to use a `web worker` to solve the problem, so we can get better performance.

Here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Emisor de video</title>
    <script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="btn">emitir</button>
    <video src="" id="video" style="height: 600px; width: 800px;" autoplay="true"></video>
    <canvas id="preview"></canvas>
    <p id="status">loading</p>
    <p>alto</p>
    <input type="number" name="" id="alto" value="720">
    <p>ancho</p>
    <input type="number" name="" id="ancho" value="380">
</body>

<script>
    var canvas = document.querySelector("#preview");
    var video = document.querySelector("#video");
    var socket = io();
    var fps = 0;
    var ss = true;
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var btn = document.querySelector("#btn");

    function message(s) {
        document.getElementById("status").innerText = s;
    }

    function loadcam(stream) {
        video.srcObject = stream;
        message("Cámara funcionando");
    }

    function errloadcam() {
        message("err> no se pudo cargar la cámara");
    }
    let skip = 0
    function ver(video, content, skipframe) {

        content.drawImage(video, 0, 0, content.canvas.width, content.canvas.height);
        if (skipframe) {
            if (skip == 1) {
                skip = 0
                socket.emit("stream1", canvas.toDataURL("image/webp", 0.5));
            } else {
                skip++;
                console.log("skiping");
            }
        } else {
            canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {

                var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob, { type: 'image/webp' });
                socket.emit("stream1", url);

            });
           // socket.emit("stream1", canvas.toDataURL("image/webp"));
        } 

        fps++;
    }


    btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.getUserMedia({ video: true }, loadcam, errloadcam);
        }

        var alto = document.getElementById("alto").value;
        var ancho = document.getElementById("ancho").value;

        canvas.width = alto;
        canvas.height = ancho;
        context.height = canvas.height;
        context.width = canvas.width;

        function loop() {
            ver(video, context, true);
            requestAnimationFrame(loop);
        }

        loop();
        setInterval(() => {
            console.log(fps);
            fps = 0
        }, 1000)
    });
</script>

</html>
```

and this is the code for the client

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Heaven style</title>
    <script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="msg"></p>
    <img id="play" alt="" src="" important="high">
</body>
<script>
    function message(params) {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerText = params
    }
    let fps = 0
    var socket = io();
    function createBlobURL(url) {
    blobURLs.push(url);
}
    socket.on('stream1', (image) => {
        let img = document.getElementById("play");
        img.src = image
        fps++
    })

    var s = setInterval(() => {
        console.log("limpieza completada>: " + blobURLs)
        revokeAllBlobURLs()
        message("fps: " + fps)
        fps = 0
    }, 1000)
</script>

</html>
```

and this is for the server (Node.js)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);



app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/public"));

http.listen(80,()=> {
    console.log("Servidor funcionando")
})

let fps = 0
io.on("connection",(socket)=>{
    socket.on("stream1",(image)=>{
        socket.broadcast.emit("stream1",image);
        fps++;
    })
    socket.on("stream2",(image)=>{
        socket.broadcast.emit("stream2",image);
        fps++;
    })

})

setInterval(() => {
  console.log(fps);
  fps = 0;
},1000)
```

Use more than one thread to get better performance converting an image to an encoded base64 url.

Comment: I would try to avoid base64 encoding each frame.  [Some tips in comments and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59478402/how-do-i-send-image-to-server-via-socket-io)

Comment: there any alternative for the encoding?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can win much doing so: To be able to generate the data: URL in a Worker you'd need to transfer the canvas image to said worker and that's probably where the culprit is anyway rather than in the encoding.
Also, only `OffscreenCanvas` is available in a Worker, and they don't support `toDataURL()`, only `convertTolBlob()`, so if you really want to try it out, you'd `createImageBitmap(canvas)` first, in order to get the `<canvas>` image, hopefully that doesn't require a readback from the GPU, but at least in Firefox it will. Then you'd transfer the resulting `ImageBitmap` to your worker where you'd draw that `ImageBitmap` on the `OffscreenCanvas` (in itself adding more work on the GPU since it has now to do 2 rendering operations), then grab the data as a `Blob` from it using `convertToBlob()`, which produces the same GPU lock that `toDataURL()` on the main thread would produce, and then convert that Blob to a base64 string manually (you may prefer to send the Blob directly to your ws, avoiding that last step, even if, once again, I doubt it's the culprit).